# Growing prime sieve

Tags: c++, primes

I tried writing a prime sieve that grows as needed.
I've only just started learning C++ so any feedback on idioms is extra welcome!

The header:

```
#ifndef prime_sieve_h__
#define prime_sieve_h__

#include <vector>

class prime_sieve {
  private:
    std::vector<bool> prime;
    int upto;

    void size_up(int n);

  public:
    prime_sieve();
    prime_sieve(int n);

    bool is_prime(int n);
    bool operator[] (const int nIndex);
};

#endif
```

And the implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "prime_sieve.h"

#define PRIME_SIEVE_DEFAULT_CAPACITY 1

prime_sieve::prime_sieve() : prime_sieve(PRIME_SIEVE_DEFAULT_CAPACITY) {}

prime_sieve::prime_sieve(int m) {
  int n = std::max(3, m); // Filling in three elements already.
  prime = std::vector<bool>(n, true);
  prime[0] = false;
  prime[1] = false;
  prime[2] = true;
  upto = 1;

  size_up(n);
}

void prime_sieve::size_up(int m) {
  if (upto * upto >= m) { return; } // Don't need to size up
  int p = upto * upto; // Previous size
  int newupto = upto;
  while (newupto * newupto < m) { newupto++; } // Need to size up
  int n = newupto * newupto; // Upto upto^2
  prime.resize(n + 1, true); // Get new elements ready

  // First sieve the lower primes again because the newest elements haven't been
  // checked for them yet.
  for (int i = 2; i < upto; ++i) {
    if (prime[i]) {
      for (int j = std::max(i * (p / i) + i, i + i); j <= n; j += i) {
        prime[j] = false;
      }
    }
  }

  // Then sieve the primes above what was already checked.
  int i;
  for (i = upto; i * i <= n; ++i) {
    if (prime[i]) {
      for (int j = i + i; j <= n; j += i){
        prime[j] = false;
      }
    }
  }
  upto = i - 1; // Counted one too many.
}

bool prime_sieve::is_prime(int n) {
  size_up(n);
  return prime[n];
}

bool prime_sieve::operator[] (const int n) {
  return is_prime(n);
}
```

How should I test this? The only thing I though of was to test some known cases.

Answer (score 3):

`upto` is a redundant variable. It's hard for me to tell what it is you're actually using it for, but you're already keeping your sieve in a dynamic container that keeps track of its own size. `prime.size()` should be how many values you've sieved up to. I'm not entirely sure what you're using `upto`, but keeping track of redundant state is very error-prone!

**namings**

`prime` is not the best name for that container (or any container) - perhaps `sieve`? Also `size_up()` should be called `resize()` for consistency with other container types.

**repetition**

Your logic with the squares doesn't make sense to me. If you want to check the primality of `n`, you need to make sure that your container is just at least that size. So I would write the top something like:

```
void prime_sieve::resize(int n) {
    if (sieve.size() > n) return;

    size_t old = sieve.size();
    sieve.resize(n+1, true);

    // ...
}
```

Next, the important thing to see is that we have two largely identical loops. We iterate on `i` over some range, and then if `sieve[i]`, we iterate over `j` in some range by steps of `i` up to `n` setting `sieve[j]` to false. As a function:

```
void prime_sieve::resieve(size_t from, size_t to, size_t jstart) {
    for (; from != to; ++from) {
        if (sieve[from]) {
            for (size_t j = std::max(jstart/from*from, from*from); j < sieve.size(); j += i) {
                sieve[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can start at `i^2` for `j`, since every lower multiple of `i` we already know isn't prime (because it's a multiple of some other number smaller than `i` and we've already done those). With that, our `resize()` function in its entirety is:

```
void prime_sieve::resize(int n) {
    if (sieve.size() > n) return;

    size_t old = sieve.size();
    sieve.resize(n+1, true);

    resieve(2, old, old); // from 2 to old, starting at old
    resieve(old, sieve.size(), 0); // from old to n
}
```

**defining constants**

If you're going to have a `PRIME_SIEVE_DEFAULT_CAPACITY`, it should be a `static constexpr size_t`, not a `#define`. Stay away from macros.

**constructor**

You have:

```
prime_sieve::prime_sieve(int m) {
  int n = std::max(3, m); // Filling in three elements already.
  prime = std::vector<bool>(n, true);
  prime[0] = false;
  prime[1] = false;
  prime[2] = true;
  upto = 1;

  size_up(n);
}
```

This is less than ideal - we're constructing the sieve then just reconstructing it anyway. Just do it with the right values outright:

```
prime_sieve::prime_sieve(int m)
: sieve(std::max(3, m), true)
{
    sieve[0] = sieve[1] = false;
    resieve(2, sieve.size(), 0); // now that we have this handy helper,
                                 // we can use it here!
}
```

Comment: What does `prime_sieve::prime_sieve(int m) : sieve(std::max(3, m), true)` do exactly? (again, new to c++)

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef prime_sieve_h__
#define prime_sieve_h__
```

You are using a reserved name due to the double underscore; you should adjust your naming convention for header guards (e.g. only use a single trailing underscore).

The relevant passage from the C++11 standard, 17.6.4.3.2 `[global.names]`, says

> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> - Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

Comment: I would also note that macros are traditionally all uppercase to avoid clashes with other identifiers.